# Symfony - render twig code in controller

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php, rendering

I need to build a customizer for my customers. They will be able to choose between multiple templates for their subdomain.

In order to do that, I took the following path :

- Store templates in the DB with twig tags for the user's data
- When needing to display a preview of a template, I would get it from the DB
- Then I would render it in the controller and send the resulting HTML as a variable to the main template

I'm not succeeding into rendering in the controller. I tried several things, but the closest I got is this :

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array(
    'code.html' => $site->getTheme()->getCode(),
));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$code = $twig->render('code.html', array( "test" => "CUSTOM DATA" ));
```

But I miss a `use` statement :

```
Attempted to load class "Twig_Loader_Array" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I'm not sure if it's the right path though.

So, if it is, please help me find out what `use` statement to use. More generally, how do you find what `use` statement should be used ?

If it's not the right strategy according to you, please feel free to explain me how dumb my idea was :)

[EDIT] So thanks to @DarkBee I found this solution that works, but I'm not sure whether I should do this or not :

```
use Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader;
use Twig\Environment;
...
$loader = new ArrayLoader(array(
    'code.html' => $site->getTheme()->getCode(),
));
$twig = new Environment($loader);
$code = $twig->render('code.html', array( "test" => "CUSTOM DATA" ));
```

So if it's ok, great. If it's wrong (or again, if I'm wrong in the strategy choices), please tell me why and what would be better.

Comment: Seems you are not using `Twih 2.X`, or at least not the new  `ArrayLoader` class, so the use statement would be `use Twig_Loader_Array` or just do `$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Array(..)`

Comment: As where to look for this. I just google for the source code of the filename. The namespace is always in the source file. You could also query the [github](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Twig_Loader_Array&type=)

Comment: I just checked the Twig version : `const VERSION = '2.4.3';` so yes, it's Twig 2.X ! Also, `use Twig_Loader_Array` doesn't work (same error) and I tried, following your link, to modify the code as I show in the edit of the question - it worked but I'm really not sure if that's what I should do !

Comment: No, you should def use the new `ArrayLoader` because they will prolly deprecate the older one in newer versions

Comment: So I got the right way :) thanks